# 404 not found. CSV and Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

im trying to convert links into images in different formats (jpg,pdf) and so on. I tried it earlier today and it worked fine until the last 500 links because my internet had a hiccup. So I removed all the converted links and was going to go at it again, but this time nothing is working. The program is running but cant seem to download the image and thus getting the error "404not found"

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'tempfile'
require 'uri'
require 'csv'

DOWNLOAD_DIR = "#{Dir.pwd}/BD/"
CSV_FILE = "#{Dir.pwd}/konvertera.csv"

def downloadFile(id, url, format)
  open("#{DOWNLOAD_DIR}#{id}.#{format}", "wb+") do |file|
    file << open(url).read
    puts "Successfully downloaded #{url} to #{DOWNLOAD_DIR}#{id}.#{format}"
  end
rescue
  puts "404 not found #{url}"
end


CSV.foreach(CSV_FILE, headers: true, col_sep: ";") do |row|
 puts row[0],row[1]
 next unless row[0] && row[1]
 id = row[0]
 format = row[1].match(/BD\.(.+)$/)&.captures.first
 puts format
 url = row[1].gsub ".pdf", ""
 downloadFile(id, url, format)
end
```

Comment: It is difficult to say what is the matter without any debug info. What is the value of `url` in `open(url).read`?

Comment: If you are asking for the url that is being converted, here it is. http://www.finfo.se/www.artdb.finfo.se/cgi-bin/lankkod.dll/lev?knr=7770566&art=001339534&typ=BD.pdf the regex is there to remove the ".pdf" otherwise the link does not work

Comment: I am asking about `url` in `downloadFile` method. What it exactly is?

Comment: I'm sorry I dont really get what you are asking for. Is this the answer? (the url's are links to either pdf(documents) and jpgs(links). I'm kind of a noob at coding and this is my first time using ruby. Sorry :/.

Comment: If you get an exception that means that `open(url)` failed in someway. Mostly it is because of incorrect url given. That is why I am asking you about `url` variable exact value in `downloadFile` method.

Comment: That is the thing, I'm not getting an exception. The file is getting downloaded, but when I try to open the file, it's broken. EXAMPLE -  001339534
http://www.finfo.se/www.artdb.finfo.se/cgi-bin/lankkod.dll/lev?knr=7770566&art=001339534&typ=BD.pdf
pdf
404 not found http://www.finfo.se/www.artdb.finfo.se/cgi-bin/lankkod.dll/lev?knr=7770566&art=001339534&typ=BD

Comment: Maybe you should try to open file in another mode. Not `wb+` but just `w`.

Comment: Still I think that you have problem with urls because none of this can't be opened in browser.

Comment: http://www.finfo.se/www.artdb.finfo.se/cgi-bin/lankkod.dll/lev?knr=7770566&art=001339535&typ=BD Can you open this?

Comment: Nope. And `open(...)` throws `Errno::ETIMEDOUT` exception. Are you there must be double `www`?

Comment: The link works for me when I click it